# How to dump a serialized java object

Tags: java, serialization

I would like to compare 2 different methods to serialize Java objects (both of them are using their own child class of ObjectOutputStream). Is there a way to dump a serialized object file so that I can see the structure of the serialized instance? I'm thinking of something similar to an ASN.1 dump where I can see first comes an integer value then comes a SEQUENCE with the members x, y, z, etc. etc. and it might look like this:

```
class Myobject
|
-- integer: 2
-- String: "some chars"
-- class anothernestedclass:
   |
   -- boolean: false
   and so on...
```

Comment: If you're outputting the properties of the object (as it looks like), won't a dump for the same object created by both serialization methods be the same?

Comment: No because with the 2 OOS there are different implementations of replaceObject() which actually replace some of the properties by sth else.

Comment: This is a project of mine indeed, made difficult by the fact that custom (de)serialization is possible and presents security issues, and private methods are legally inaccessible as of Java SE 16 or so. The java object serialization protocol is an open format, in case you would like to create your own tool :) I haven't found one myself.